# Copy file outside NuGet package directory

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to create a NuGet package that copies a file to a folder outside the package folder (i.e. in the destination project's root)?

I have the following  declaration:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\net40\Ionic.Zip.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="bin\net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="Web References\myWebService\*.*" target="content\Web References\myWebService" />
  </files>
```

Currently this creates the Web References folder inside the package folder, but I would like to create the Web References folder in the project root instead. I've tried changing the path to "..\Web References\myWebService", but that caused the Web References folder not to be copied at all.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the destination location of the package content is not configurable right now.
This is something we are tracking for next release here @ http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1914

Comment: Has this feature been implemented? If so, can you provide a link that describes how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

That should be the behavior. NuGet should create the WebReferences folder under the project root. It shouldn't create the folder inside the package folder. Do you have an example of the package?